# reasonable handling of ScriptException thrown by JSR223 Rhino

Tags: java, exception, rhino, jsr223

I'm starting to run into the dirty little secrets of what is an otherwise very useful JSR223 scripting environment.

I'm using the builtin version of Rhino shipped with Java 6 SE, accessing it through JSR223's `ScriptingEngine` et al.

When I get an exception caused by a Java object I've exported into the Javascript environment, it is a `ScriptingException` that wraps a `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException` that wraps my real exception (e.g. `UnsupportedOperationException` or whatever)

The `ScriptingException` returns null for getFileName() and -1 for getLineNumber().
But when I look at the message and at the debugger, the `WrappedException` has the correct filename and line number, it's just not publishing it via the ScriptingException's getter methods.

Great. **Now what do I do?** I don't know how I'm going to use sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.wrappedException which isn't a public class anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh. Java 6's Rhino does the same thing (doesn't publish the file name / line number / etc via ScriptingException's methods) with `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException` and who knows how many other exceptions.

The only reasonable way I can think of to handle this is to use reflection. Here's my solution.

```
void handleScriptingException(ScriptingException se)
{ 
    final Throwable t1 = se.getCause();
    String lineSource = null;
    String filename = null;
    Integer lineNumber = null;

    if (hasGetterMethod(t1, "sourceName"))
    {
        lineNumber = getProperty(t1, "lineNumber", Integer.class);
        filename = getProperty(t1, "sourceName", String.class);
        lineSource = getProperty(t1, "lineSource", String.class);
    }
    else
    {
        filename = se.getFileName();
        lineNumber = se.getLineNumber();
    }
    /* do something with this info */
}

static private Method getGetterMethod(Object object, String propertyName)
{
    String methodName = "get"+getBeanSuffix(propertyName);
    try {
        Class<?> cl = object.getClass();
        return cl.getMethod(methodName);
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { 
        return null;
        /* gulp */ 
    }
}
static private String getBeanSuffix(String propertyName) {
    return propertyName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
       +propertyName.substring(1);  
}   
static private boolean hasGetterMethod(Object object, String propertyName) 
{
    return getGetterMethod(object, propertyName) != null;
}
static private <T> T getProperty(Object object, String propertyName, 
        Class<T> cl) {
    try {
        Object result = getGetterMethod(object, propertyName).invoke(object);
        return cl.cast(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```